# How to pull the value of a taxonomy term into the html.tpl.php files

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

How does one  pull the value of a taxonomy term into the `html.tpl.php` file?

I know this needs to be done in the `template.php` file, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the function [template_preprocess_html](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x) in your `template.php`.

For example.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$vars){
    // $tid - id of your taxonomy term
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $vars['head_title'] = $term->name;
}
```

Also, copy the `html.tpl.php` file to the directory in your theme, where all the template files are located. And clear cache.

Comment: Thank you for the direction.  I think I need to explain more.  I populated a field on all nodes and all tax terms with a specific value pulled from a taxonomy list.  The field name is the same on both nodes and tax terms.  For example field_genre. How can I pull this value into the html.tpl.php file?

Comment: You can install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module for Drupal, then inside of the yourtheme_preprocess_html function watch the value of your field using a debug function, such as kpr($term) or another one.